# Should I use 'Strip Debug Symbols During Copy' and 'Strip Linked Produts' with Google Analytics?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, google-analytics, testflight

I have used TestFlight for remote crash reporting. Now I'm using Google Analytics for that.

TestFlight recommends 'Strip Debug Symbols During Copy' and 'Strip Linked Produts' to be disabled. Google Analytics - no. Should I remove them after I have changed TestFlight to Google Analytics?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This depends on how the crash reports are being symbolicated:

1. If you can upload a dSYM to get symbolicated crash reports, you **should strip** the debug symbols. This has the benefit of getting line numbers and sometimes up to 50% smaller application binaries.
2. If you can **NOT** upload a dSYM for symbolication, and can't/don't want to download the crash reports and symbolicate them on your own Mac, you **should not strip** the symbols to get at least something. Symbolication on your Mac will only work if you archive the dSYM of those builds and you can download crash reports in standard format.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But what's about 'Strip Linked Product' option?

Comment: See the documentation for `STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT` at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html Only if this is set to `YES` the stripping would be done. Xcode projects have this set to `YES` by default on project level.

Comment: Is it enough to set only one of these properties to NO to stop stripping?

Comment: You want debug symbols to remain in the binary? Then both should be set to `NO`.

Comment: Do you know do these options required by Google Analytics for proper crash reporting?

Comment: The corresponding website at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/exceptions doesn't say anything about symbolication. But it shows that it only collects unhandled exceptions and no crashes caused by other signals which means it will only report a subset of your actual apps crashes. Since it doesn't say anything about symbolication, you may have to try it out and see. But overall doesn't look like a good solution for collecting crash reports to me.

Comment: I tried different values of the options - app size is absolutelly the same.

Comment: Please create a new question if you have problems getting this to work and add some more information, like how you build the product and the current settings on target and project level.

Comment: I don't understand your intent/wording here. "you should not strip the symbols to get at least something." If I don't want to symbolicate/inspect crash reports, then why should I not strip it all?